# Office-ui-fabric-react : error in components & BaseComponent.d.ts file

Tags: error, spfx, office-ui-fabric-react, fabric

add **office-ui-fabric-react** package in SPFX react webpart using

```
<!-- language: lang-ps -->

npm --save install office-ui-fabric-react
```

then add

```
<!-- language: lang-ts -->

import { SearchBox } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/SearchBox';
import './SearchBox.Small.Example.scss';`
```

then run `gulp serve` command and following error occurred

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(18,59): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(18,61): error TS1005: '>' expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(18,63): error TS1109: Expression expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(23,63): error TS1005: ',' expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(30,19): error TS1005: ':' expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(18,89): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'P'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(18,92): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'S'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(29,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'boolean'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(56,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'string'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\BaseComponent.d.ts(60,37): error TS2693: 'IDisposable' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Button\Button.Props.d.ts(13,44): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AllHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Button\Button.Props.d.ts(123,22): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Button\Button.Props.d.ts(123,70): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AnchorHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Calendar\Calendar.d.ts(20,8): error TS2411: Property 'dayPicker' of type 'CalendarDay' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Calendar\Calendar.d.ts(21,8): error TS2411: Property 'monthPicker' of type 'CalendarMonth' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Checkbox\Checkbox.Props.d.ts(15,46): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Checkbox\Checkbox.Props.d.ts(53,23): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\ChoiceGroup\ChoiceGroup.Props.d.ts(5,49): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\CommandBar\CommandBar.d.ts(22,8): error TS2411: Property 'focusZone' of type 'FocusZone' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\DatePicker\DatePicker.d.ts(17,8): error TS2411: Property 'textField' of type 'TextField' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\DetailsList\DetailsHeader.d.ts(57,8): error TS2411: Property 'root' of type 'FocusZone' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Dropdown\Dropdown.d.ts(20,8): error TS2411: Property 'focusZone' of type 'FocusZone' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Facepile\Facepile.Props.d.ts(43,48): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\FocusZone\FocusZone.Props.d.ts(50,30): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ReactHTML'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\GroupedList\GroupedList.d.ts(19,8): error TS2411: Property 'list' of type 'List' is not assignable to string index type 'ReactInstance'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\HoverCard\HoverCard.Props.d.ts(9,17): error TS2430: Interface 'IHoverCardProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement | HoverCard>'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Image\Image.Props.d.ts(3,43): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ImgHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Label\Label.Props.d.ts(3,43): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'LabelHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Link\Link.Props.d.ts(6,42): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AllHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Rating\Rating.Props.d.ts(6,44): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AllHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\SearchBox\SearchBox.Props.d.ts(7,47): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\TextField\TextField.Props.d.ts(28,47): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AllHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\pickers\AutoFill\BaseAutoFill.Props.d.ts(40,50): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\pickers\BasePicker.Props.d.ts(177,43): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
Error - typescript - node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\pickers\PickerItem.Props.d.ts(1,51): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AllHTMLAttributes'.

Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 3.27 s
 "TypeScript error(s) occurred."
```

Comment: same issue here, just upgraded from 2.34.2 to  4.32 and started getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Looks like SPFx is on Typescript 2.2 and using that to build your webpart. The latest version of Fabric UI React seems only to work with Typescript 2.4+ of what I've read. Didn't find a way to upgrade the typescript version used with spfx so I reverted to the Fabric UI React which ships with the SPFx webpart (you don't have to install this in your package,json) and it is working again.